# How to stop my double bass pedals from squeaking?

Tags: maintenance, drums

I have had my double kick pedal for at least a year and a half now and I've started to notice a squeaking when the left pedal is pressed (the slave pedal.)

I've tried oiling the bearings and it hasn't stopped it. The springs have been well kept too so I cant see it coming from them. Is there any other point of motion in the pedals that needs oiling or is it just a sign that the pedals are getting old?

Comment: Ah, you're a drummer, not a double bass player with a stomp box!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Everything that moves should be looked at, not just the bearings.

This includes:

- bearings
- springs
- hinge
- chain (if it uses a chain)
- universal joint (if it has one)

You could get a friend to put their ear close to it while you press it - that could help you pin down the problem. (Don't hit your friend in the head...)